# JS Mobile Menu Error: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, wordpress, addeventlistener

The mobile menu does not close due to this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Here is the JS:

```js
//MOBILE MENU TOGGLE//

var menu_element = document.getElementById('menu-mobile-open');

var menu_exists = !!menu_element;

if(menu_exists){

    menu_element.addEventListener('click', function(){

        document.body.classList.add('menu-mobile-active');

    });


    document.getElementById('menu-mobile-close').addEventListener('click', function(){

        document.body.classList.remove('menu-mobile-active');

    });

}
```

Comment: Are you sure both elements,  #menu-mobule-active and #menu-mobile-close are loaded on the page with the correct id?

Comment: I honestly have no idea...I'll see if I can figure out where that would be and if they're missing or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code, and instead of adding and removing class on click events, you can toggle that class. A sample example for menu button toggle -

```
let menu = document.getElementById("menu-button");

menu.addEventListener("click", function(){
    menu.classList.toggle("active");
})
```

On each click, active class will be toggled. If it is present, then it will be removed. If it is not present, then it will be added.

In this case, all you need to make sure is that the menu button's id matches with the id that you're fetching in JavaScript. You do not need to check for it's existence/visibility on website, it doesn't seem necessary to me, as event listener will apply only when it exists anyway.